# Validation of DateTime against another DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, datetime

I need to ensure that a DateTime variable named `start` falls approximately a month after the current date. The only means that I am aware of to do this is to create another DateTime variable that is hard-coded to be precisely one month (or four weeks, preferably) after the current date, and compare the two.

Is there a more efficient way to do this, without creating another object that I will do nothing with?

Comment: Is it one month or four weeks then? Those are not equal measures.

Comment: four weeks are preferable, edited accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  DateTime start = new DateTime(2015, 12, 25);
  if (start > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(28))
  {
      // Do something
  }
```

Comment: When comparing dates as opposed to times, is there any real advantage to `UtcNow` providing the server date is correct?

Comment: @Wolfish Habit of working on multi-time zone systems! It entirely depends on your circumstance if you only ever transact in one time-zone and all the servers are also in that time zone then no - absolutely no advantage and you can simply use DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)

Comment: Good point. This will eventually become a multi time zone app, I think I'll use it. Thanks!

Comment: @Wolfish - ensure that you store all relevant dates in UTC - then calculations become easy. Then simply display in the relevant timezone depending on the user.

Comment: Not so simple, unfortunately. The user also inputs a date, so it becomes different according to the timezone. additionally, cultural formats also complicate the mix somewhat.

Comment: @Wolfish - agreed it's always a headache - however I meant always convert and store your dates in UTC in the database. If you store a distinct preferred timezone for each user then conversion to and from UTC is not too bad. Then whenever any date calculations are performed either in the database or in code - you know you are working with UTC across the board.

Comment: Conversion to UTC is probably the safest route to follow, countries that span more than one timezone are included in the mix here.

Answer (score 1):

if 4 weeks is a must, then;

```
if((start-DateTime.Now).Days>=28)
    {

    }
```

Comment: @CSL wolfish said: "to be precisely one month (or four weeks) after the current date,"